# How do you start doing UX design?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer

I've done research and I understand the purpose of UX but there aren't any actual resources on starting UX for someone without a related job or knowledge. Now before you say yes there are, here is what I mean.
I wanted to learn web development, I looked up how to start. Everyone said learn HTML and CSS. I followed a couple online classes and started learning them.

Where/what is the equivalent for UX?
I've read countless "beginner UX" articles but I've just ended up overwhelmed and frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied a MOOC program in edx, called User Experience (UX) Research and Design MicroMasters. It is free and I think it provided a good overview what UX field involves, as well as some tools, techniques and starting points. It has nine courses in total, including for example design itself and user research. You can start from the introduction course and decide from there what other courses you are interested in, for me wireframing and prototyping courses were particularly interesting and useful.